# How to only show the faces of an object based on relation to another object

Tags: modifiers, faces, constraints

I'd like to only show the faces of an object that another object can "see". So far I've been able to achieve this by putting a bounding box around the object I wan't to be partially seen and clipping it. Then having the bounding box offset a bit based on the position of my "Seeing" object.

**This approach resulted in the following:**
[image]

What I came up with sorta works but I want to achieve is something that hides the faces instead of doing a hard mask on it which makes it looks like it's been sliced through.

**Desired effect**

[image]

------ Update -------

Based on feedback from @ZargulTheWizard (thank you!) I was able to make some progress but still am not quite there.

**Object into Alpha** succeeded in revealing part of the object based on the cones position but 1) had a hard mask instead of hiding faces 2) would only reveal in one direction - the goal is to always have the side facing the cone be visible
[image]

[image]

**Normal into Alpha** gave me the visual effect I was hoping for in hiding entire faces instead of across them but does not react at all to the cone's being position.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I might try using the object as a texture coordinates and lining that up with the material alpha value, and then maybe throw in some back face culling so it is not visible from the inside.

Comment: Tried your approach and got some interesting results but am a bit stuck. I updated my post with your idea - would you mind giving me some feedback on it? Feels close!